# Windows Forms event "On Select Tab"?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I'm building a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application in C#. How do I trigger code when a certain tab on a tab menu is selected?

Comment: You mean by Tab Menu, TabControl, don't you?

Comment: `tabControl.TabPages[tabControl.SelectedIndex]` gives you the `TabPage` at that index.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think it is the `TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Just look at MSDN. I took it from there. Suppose you named your tab control `tabControl1`.
You need to subscribe to this event using:

```
tabContrl1.TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged += tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

And add the event handler

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

   MessageBox.Show("You are in the TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged event.");
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of this line of code being used in a sample program?  I just don't know what to do with the code you provided, thanks!

Answer (score 20):

The [`TabControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx) and its [`SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event will do what you need.

For example, you have a Customer file with a `TabControl` in its details portion of the form. You want to load lazy-load this customer's transactions when the user clicks the Transactions [`TabPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage.aspx). Your code should look like this pseudo-code:

```
public partial class CustomerMgmtForm : Form {
    // Assuming the design already done, so the TabControl control exists on your form.
    public CustomerMgmtForm() {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }

    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexchanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        switch((sender as TabControl).SelectedIndex) {
            case 0:
                // Do nothing here (let's suppose that TabPage index 0 is the address information which is already loaded.
                break;
            case 1:
                // Let's suppose TabPage index 1 is the one for the transactions.
                // Assuming you have put a DataGridView control so that the transactions can be listed.
                // currentCustomer.Id can be obtained through the CurrencyManager of your BindingSource object used to data bind your data to your Windows form controls.
                dataGridview1.DataSource = GetTransactions(currentCustomer.Id);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The following are also useful while playing with the `TabControl`.

1. TabControl.TabPages.Add();
2. TabControl.TabPages.Contains();
3. TabControl.TabPages.ContainsKey();
4. TabControl.TabPages.Insert();
5. TabControl.TabPages.Remove();
6. TabControl.TabPages.RemoveAt();
7. TabControl.TabPages.RemoveByKey().

Using the [`TabControl.TabPageCollection Members`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpagecollection_members.aspx).

**EDIT #1**

> For selecting a specific tab, it can only be identified by 0, 1, 2, and not the tab name?

Yes, you might as well increment or decrement the [`TabControl.SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindex.aspx) property to make a specific [`TabPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage.aspx) selected/active.

One thing though, make sure you don't index a `TabPage` out of the `TabPages.Count - 1`, since the start index is 0, otherwise you'll get an [`IndexOutOfRangeException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception.aspx) thrown.

To continue with our example where we have two pages, the Address information and the Transactions:

```
// Will automatically change the selected tab to the Transactions TabPage.
tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1; 

// Considering there a count of two TabPages, the first is indexed at 0, and the second at 1.  
// Setting the SelectedIndex property to 2 will throw.
tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 2;
```

*Note: Any change to `TabControl.SelectedIndex` property will trigger the `TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged` event.*

Comment: For selecting a specific tab, it can only be identified by 0, 1, 2, and not the tab name?

Comment: Please see my edit for an answer to this commented question. =)

Answer (score 5):

> For selecting a specific tab, can it only be identified by 0, 1, 2, and not the tab name?

You can do this by adding the event listener to the actual tab rather than to the tab control.

If you had a tab called tabHistory, you could add the following line in the designer.

```
this.tabHistory.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.tabHistory_Enter);
```

Then just add your method to catch the event.

```
private void tabHistory_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hey! Ive got focus");
}
```

Comment: It works only when also clicked in the tab form. That's 2 clicks with the change click!

Comment: I total have 3 tabs, I just want to track the 2nd tab.
I hide the headers of the tab, so I am controlling change of tab on button click.
I tried this solution, but it's not working for me.
Problem:
- tabPage2_Enter invoking two times
- One when, I am changing from tabPage1 to tabPage2 (this is expected)
- Other when, I am changing from tabPage2 to tabPage3 (this is not expected in my case)

NOTE: When it enters 2nd time at that time tabControl.SelectedIndex is still points to tabPage2.
Hence, I am not following this solution.

Answer (score 2):

if you for example have 3 tabs...

```
if (tabControl.SelectedTab == tabControl.TabPages[0])
               do something...
if (tabControl.SelectedTab == tabControl.TabPages[1])
               do something else...
if (tabControl.SelectedTab == tabControl.TabPages[2])
               do something else...
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if this [helps](http://en.csharp-online.net/TabControl) you. "`SelectedIndexChanged`" might help you.

Details from MSDN are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindex.aspx)