# Hide or show textbox based on different tab page selection

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

First of all I did find this which was useful but not exactly what i needed
[Windows Forms event "On Select Tab"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921483/winform-event-on-select-tab)

That only covers the selection changed event for the entire tab control and not each individual tab page.

What I need to do is hide or show certain text boxes based on which tab page i have selected. Example being below except the click event does not work. ExpenseReport and ExpenseReview are my two tabs. Any help would be appreciated!

```
private void tpExpenseReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtTripNo.Visible = true;
    txtTripNo2.Visible = false;
}

private void tpExpenseReview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtTripNo.Visible = false;
    txtTripNo2.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the TabControl's [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event.

Assuming there are only two tabs.  (If there are more, I'd use a switch statement instead of if..else)

```
tabControl1.SelectedIndex_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 0)
   {
      txtTripNo.Visible = true; 
      txtTripNo2.Visible = false; 
   }
   else
   {
      txtTripNo.Visible = false; 
      txtTripNo2.Visible = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Simple. Easy answer. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You might go like this:

```
private void tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(...)
{
    int index = tabControl.SelectedIndex;
    if (index == 0) HideTextBoxes(false);
    else HideTextBoxes(true);
}

private void HideTextBoxes(bool someSelector)
{
    txtTripNo.Visible = someSelector;
    txtTripNo2.Visible = !someSelector;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to use the `Selected` event.  It passes the actual tab that is being selected in the `TabControlEventArgs` parameter:

```
private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e) {
  if (e.TabPage == tpExpenseReport) {
    txtTripNo.Visible = true;
    txtTripNo2.Visible = false;
  } else if (e.TabPage == tpExpenseReview) {
    txtTripNo.Visible = false;
    txtTripNo2.Visible = true;
  }
}
```